# ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5 Xcode

Tags: ios, linker

```
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: The Issue was with the current SDK, if any one faces this problem please change the project Settings and choose the SDK available;

Answer (score 0):

When I have an ANE build in iPhone-ARM mode, and linking it with iPhoneSimulator-SDK, which needs an ANE build in iPhone-x86 mode, the same error occurs.

Hope this can help you.