# MonoTouch 3rd Party Library Works With 4.2 But Not 5.0

Tags: ios, linker, xamarin.ios, libgcc

I have a third party library which I finally have working within my MonoTouch app. However, it will only compile for the simulator when I set the SDK to 4.2. If I set it to 5.0, the linker will fail. It *will* compile to 5.0 for an actual device. What is the gcc_s.10.5 that its asking for and where should it be located?

```
Generated /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/main.m
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0 -arch i386  -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -c /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/main.m -o /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/main.x86.o -DDEBUG  
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0   -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/RetailStuff -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework ExternalAccessory -framework QuartzCore -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise -force_load /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/libGrabbaDriver.a
Process exited with code 1, command:
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2 -miphoneos-version-min=5.0   -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/main.x86.o -o /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/RetailStuff -framework CFNetwork -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework ExternalAccessory -framework QuartzCore -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u _catch_exception_raise -force_load /var/folders/GG/GG6dZ9dzFX0vYZmJ1+6pQ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp6a32a243.tmp/libGrabbaDriver.a
ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

mtouch exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers above were on the right approach. The same problem occurred on a different project as well. In the end I upgraded from Snow Leopard to Lion, upgraded to latest xcode and its all ok now.

Answer (score 2):

`libgcc_s` is *likely* a dependency of `libGrabbaDriver.a` which you're linking your MonoTouch project with.

```
 ld: library not found for -lgcc_s.10.5
```

The name of that library *might* have changed, i.e. it's not identical on my iOS 5.1 system.

```
 /Applications//Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
```

From there I would assume you need to:

- link your application with the newer library (hoping there's no internal changes);
- rebuild the native library to have it linked with the right (newer) version of `libgcc_s`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your system is in an inconsistent state.

MonoTouch does not try to link with libgcc_s, and a [bit](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=6635.0) [of](http://forum.openframeworks.cc/index.php?topic=5738.0) [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664891/ld-library-not-found-for-lgcc-s-10-5-xcode) shows that it doesn't look related to MonoTouch at all.

I would try to uninstall and reinstall Xcode again (you might have to install MonoTouch again too, since Xcode might delete it in some circumstances):